# Regex that matches only if the specified char occurs one time

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a regex to catch invoice numbers in some text, by working with the char '/'.

Picture this text:

```
20/10/2000
asdasd 1234/12 asdasdasd
```

I want to build a regex that would only capture "1234/12" as being a valid match. Problem is it gets the date as well.

At the moment my regex is looking like this:

```
(?:(\d+[\/]{1}\d+)(?!\1{2}))
```

Comment: You could add whitespace boundaries `(?<!\S)\d+\/\d+(?!\S)` or `(?<!\S)\d{4}\/\d{2}(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/VAehze/1

Comment: `\s(\d+\/\d+)\s `

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you to go with a regex pattern

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))\d+\/\d+(?=(?:[\s;,.]|$))
```

which searches for the invoice number inside of text.

---

Test and see explanation of this regex pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/RyOolL/3).